# Meaning of unique umvue

Tags: self-study, estimation, bernoulli-distribution, umvue

For a random sample of size $n$ from Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$, find the unique UMVUE of $1-p(1-p)$.

I found that $1-X_1$ is a UMVUE of $1-p(1-p)$. But can't this $X_1$ be replaced by any of $X_2$ or $X_3$ or. . . $X_n$. In that case is this UMVUE unique?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2687375/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404136/find-umvue-of-p3

Answer (score 3):

Generally, an UMVUE is essentially unique. The estimator you provided is not an UMVUE though, indeed it is not even unbiased!!

Notice that  $\mathrm E[1-X]= 1-\mathrm E[X]=1-p$ provided that our random variable is a Bernoulli with parameter $p$.

I'd suggest to proceed finding the UMVUE for $p(1-p)$. Then, using the fact that given an UMVUE estimator $U$ for the unknown parameter $\theta$, $a+bU$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$ is UMVUE for $a+b\theta$, you retrive the desired estimator.

The starting point should be, for example a trivial unbiased estimator like $U= X_1(1-X_2)$, then using Rao-Blackwell theorem and the sufficient and complete statistic $T$ for $\theta$, i.e. $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, you'd find your estimator. This last result is the so called [Lehman-Scheffé theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem).

Comment: The MVUE is the conditional expectation of any unbiased estimator, given the value of the complete sufficient statistic. Is that what you mean in your last sentence?

Comment: Yes, exactly it should be the lehman-scheffè theorem

Comment: Ok. Might help the OP to make that more explicit. Good answer +1